# CODE::BLOCKS - why path is incorrect?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am trying to configure project in CODE::BLOCKS according this tutorial:
Playing with OpenCL: Gaussian Blurring by Lefteris

I have set linking to

```
C:\Program Files\AMD APP\lib\x86\OpenCL.lib
and
W:\___NEW PROJECTS\GaussianBlur\Gaussian_with_OpenCL\refu.dll
libraries
Compiler Search folder to:
C:\Program Files\AMD APP\include\CL
and Search directories Linker folder to
C:\Program Files\AMD APP\lib\x86\
```

Now I run this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And I got these errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Gaussian_with_OpenCL (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
 [b]Files\AMD[/b]||No such file or directory|
 [b]Files\AMD[/b]||No such file or directory|
 [b]PROJECTS[/b]\GaussianBlur\Gaussian_with_OpenCL\refu.dll||No such file or directory|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

**Why the path is incorrect and does not correspond with the data saved in settings of project?**

Code::Blocks v13.12 running on Windows XP

Edit:

```
After I added quotes I have these errors:
mingw32-g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files\AMD APP\lib\x86\" -o bin\Debug\Gaussian_with_OpenCL.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -lOpenCL  "C:\Program Files\AMD APP\lib\x86\OpenCL.lib" -lrefu.dll "C:\Program Files\AMD APP\lib\x86\OpenCL.lib" "W:\___NEW PROJECTS\GaussianBlur\Gaussian_with_OpenCL\refu.dll"
mingw32-g++.exe: error: Files\AMD: No such file or directory
mingw32-g++.exe: error: APP\lib\x86\OpenCL.lib -lrefu.dll C:\Program: Invalid argument
mingw32-g++.exe: error: Files\AMD: No such file or directory
mingw32-g++.exe: error: APP\lib\x86\OpenCL.lib W:\___NEW: Invalid argument
mingw32-g++.exe: error: PROJECTS\GaussianBlur\Gaussian_with_OpenCL\refu.dll: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You probably need quotes around any path with a space in it.

Comment: I added quotes pls see the errors, I updated the post.

Comment: You probably want to install your libraries so that there are no spaces in the path.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476526/wxwidgets-2-9-4-include-and-lib-gcc-lib-mswu-no-such-file-or-directory-error-on and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195297/code-blocks-13-12-build-errors-wrong-include-paths would indicate you're not the first to have these issues.

Comment: It is not possible to install it do different directory. The SDK stream is installed in directory: "C:\Program Files\AMD APP" even if I choose different directory to install to. Should I move the files of OpenCL to different directory even that the registry refers to this folder? Could the compiler of openCL even work?

Comment: Also notice that the author of the tutorial uses the same compilter GNU Compiler and he has spaces in the path names.

Answer (score 0):

No quotes help in any form. This is nothing to do with spaces but with length of the file name. Compiler sees it as old MS-DOS in form of 8 characters as for name of file and 3 characters for extension. Any longer file name/folder must be renamed.

**Solution:**
1. go to the directory you need to get the real name of
Create link to command.com; working path filed stays empty
2. submit
3. run command.com in the folder
4. in command prompt type dir
5. select the text and copy it to clipboard by enter
6. edit the text as needed and paste it to the Code::Block
Here are examples of my paths:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\AMDAPP~1\lib\x86\OpenCL.lib
```

(shortcut for `C:\Program Files\AMD APP\lib\x86\OpenCL.lib` )

```
W:\___NEW~1\GAUSSI~1\GAUSSI~2\refu.dll
```

(shortcut for `W:\___NEW_PROJECTS\GaussianBlur\Gaussian_with_OpenCL\refu.dll`)

So now it works and errors disappear. I hope this helps to others.